# Unable to load lua module in nginx docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, lua

I have a simple docker file with lua module:

```
FROM nginx:alpine 
RUN apk add --no-cache nginx-mod-http-lua
COPY config/ /etc/nginx/
```

and
nginx.conf has these three lines:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
pcre_jit on;
```

I am getting the version mismatch.

```
module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so" version 1020002 instead of 1021006 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so" version 1020002 instead of 1021006 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

I am building a docker as :

```
docker build --build-arg ENABLED_MODULES="ndk lua" -t nginxapp .
```

Comment: Hey @codebased, did you ever solve this? I am facing the same issue and am getting ab bit tired over that already :-) thanks!

Comment: No I walked away from using lua in nginx.